# Cant center secondary list items right below parent list item

Tags: html, css, list, hover

I trying to make a navbar that when you hover over one of its item it it drops down and shows another set of list items i know how to make the dropdown effect but i cant quite center the secondary list items above the parent list item

```css
.container{
    width: 90%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}


header{
    background: black;
    height: 100px;
}


.container > ul {
    height: 100px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.container >ul li{
    margin: 7px;
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid green;
}

.container >ul li,
.container > ul li a{
    list-style: none;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 4px;    
    
}

.container ul ul{
    position: absolute;

}
```

```html
 <header>
            <div class="container">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="">Home</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </header>
```

Comment: I've kind of got what i wanted with absolutely positioning it but is it the best way?

Comment: please see if this is what you are looking for: https://jsfiddle.net/KennyChoy/3q7eabsz/, it's hard to tell is this or that the best way or not, but if changing the child element's style would affect the others then it probably isn't a good approach